# Unable to add .meta file to VSTS source control

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, azure-devops

I'm trying to add a .meta file (for Unity3D project) to VSTS source control, but Visual Studio does not detect the .meta file...

What can I do to add this type of file to source control?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate which version control are you using, TFVC or Git?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc#git-and-tfvc-capabilities

Comment: What's the Version Control System do you use to manage your source code? And did you ignore `.meta` file in it?

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it; all the .meta files were hidden by default on my project - see: https://answers.unity.com/questions/932348/visible-or-hidden-meta-files-with-git.html?_ga=2.206885779.1432320745.1577222904-372842208.1571010533

So it had nothing to do with the .meta extension - it had to do with that Unity made the files hidden - and apparently hidden files are ignored by TFS.